# how to split a list of arrays and switch the position of arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a list of numpy arrays. These arrays are related to some data sets and iteration. In my list arrays are sorted firstly based on the iterations and then data sets but I want to sort them firstly based on the iterations. This is my list:

```
all_data=[np.array([[1., 5.],[1., 5.],[1., 5.]]),\
          np.array([[2., 5.],[2., 5.],[2., 5.]]),\
          np.array([[3., 5.],[3., 5.],[3., 5.]]),\
          np.array([[1., 50.],[1., 50.],[1., 50.]]),\
          np.array([[2., 50.],[2., 50.],[2., 50.]]),\
          np.array([[3., 50.],[3., 50.2],[3., 50.]]),\
          np.array([[1., 500.],[1., 500.],[1., 500.]]),\
          np.array([[2., 500.],[2., 500.],[2., 500.]]),\
          np.array([[3., 500.],[3., 500.],[3., 500.]])]
```

As it can be seen in my list, the data stored in first three arrays are presenting three iterations (from 1 to 3) of one data set (which their last column is 5). From array number 4 to 6, I have the results of the same three iterations for another data set (which their last column is 50) and last three arrays are related to another data set. I porpusefuly copied this simplified numbers to make a visualization of what I want. I have the numbers iterations and data sets as:

```
n_data_sets=3.
n_iteration=3.
```

Then I tried firstly to split my list into the number of data sets using:

```
data=[all_data[i:i + n_iteration] for i in range(0, len(all_data), n_iteration)]
```

Then I tried the following code to rearrange my list but it was not successfull:

```
re_ar=[]
for i in range (len (data)-1):
    for j in range (len(data[i])):
        re_ar.append([data[i][j], data[i+1][j]])
```

This is my expected outcome:

```
[[np.array([[1., 5.],[1., 5.],[1., 5.]]),\
  np.array([[1., 50.],[1., 50.],[1., 50.]]),\
  np.array([[1., 500.],[1., 500.],[1., 500.]])],\
 [np.array([[2., 5.],[2., 5.],[2., 5.]]),\
  np.array([[2., 50.],[2., 50.],[2., 50.]]),\
  np.array([[2., 500.],[2., 500.],[2., 500.]])],\
 [np.array([[3., 5.],[3., 5.],[3., 5.]]),\
  np.array([[3., 50.],[3., 50.2],[3., 50.]]),\
  np.array([[3., 500.],[3., 500.],[3., 500.]])]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you are saying is that you want every n-th element from the list:

```
n_iteration = 3
data=[all_data[i:: n_iteration] for i in range(n_iteration)]
```

which gives

```
[[array([[1., 5.], [1., 5.], [1., 5.]]),
  array([[ 1., 50.], [ 1., 50.], [ 1., 50.]]),
  array([[  1., 500.], [  1., 500.], [  1., 500.]])],
 [array([[2., 5.], [2., 5.], [2., 5.]]),
  array([[ 2., 50.], [ 2., 50.], [ 2., 50.]]),
  array([[  2., 500.], [  2., 500.], [  2., 500.]])],
 [array([[3., 5.], [3., 5.], [3., 5.]]),
  array([[ 3. , 50. ], [ 3. , 50.2], [ 3. , 50. ]]),
  array([[  3., 500.], [  3., 500.], [  3., 500.]])]]
```

Comment: Dear @wtw, I do appreciate your solution, it is really intelligent but I have problems with it. Just lets regard `n_data_sets=2.` and please delet all the array that their second column equals 50 (I mean the three middle array (array no 4,5, and 6)) and try your solution. I t will not be what I expected.

Comment: I believe if you switch the `n_data_sets` with `n_iteration` in your code, the problem will be solved. I mean make it as: `data=[all_data[i::n_iteration] for i in range(0, n_iteration)]`.

Comment: I'm happy with that - in your example there are 3 of both, so I may have just swapped the meaning of `n_data_sets` and `n_iteration`. Please be aware that you'll need to use integers, not floating point for the slicing, so `n_data_sets = 3` not `n_data_sets = 3.` (or `n_iteration` equivalently)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I do appreciate your time. Have you any idea how I can merge arrays stroed in each sublist? I mean concatenating all the arrays stored in first, second and their sublist with the same order?

Comment: `[np.concatenate(d) for d in data]` will concatenate the arrays in each sublist, so you'll get something like `[1, 5], [1, 5], [1, 5], [2, 5], [2, 5], [2, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5], [3, 5]' for the first sublist. The second and third sublists will be the same but with 50s and 500s

Comment: Thanks a lot for being that much supportive.